# JDesktop: How to configure resource map path?

Tags: java, swing, maven, gradle, jdesktop

I am using the org.jdesktop.application dependency and want to load some resources.
The gradle project is structured in:

- main.java.myproject
- main.resources

When I want to load the resource map using `getResourceMap()`. It does not read any properties so I think those files have to be stored in `main.java.myproject.resources`.
How can I set the path of the resource map to keep my project structure?

Code Example:

```
public MyView(SingleFrameApplication app) {
    super(app);
    initComponents();
    ResourceMap resourceMap = getResourceMap();
    resourceMap.getInteger("timeout"); // <-- NullPointerException
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Oct 19, 2019 4:00:01 PM org.jdesktop.application.Application$1 run
SEVERE: Application class myproject.MyApp failed to launch
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myproject.MyView.<init>(MyView.java:156)
    at myproject.MyApp.startup(MyApp.java:30)
    at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Application class myproject.MyApp failed to launch
    at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:177)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

    at myproject.MyView.<init>(MyView.java:156)
    at myproject.MyApp.startup(MyApp.java:30)
    at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: 1) `// <-- Error` Always copy/paste error and exception output! 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I added a stacktrace

Comment: `myproject.MyView.<init>(MyView.java:156)` If you had also posted an MRE / SSCCE, we might be able to tell which was line 156. As it is, the best advice I can offer is.. See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)